# How to make std::cout discarding certain symbols at its output

Tags: c++

There is a device sending byte stream using UTF-8. Among them ESC symbols present, such as `0x1B[?25h` `0x1B[nJ` `0x1B[u` etc. which are later printed with `std::cout`.

How to force `std::cout` to discard this ANSI escape code sequencies in printing outside?

Comment: There's no such functionality that's built into `std::cout`. You will need to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: Strip the escape codes yourself before handing them to stdout, or apply a filter to your program that does it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am working with Qt's `QSerialPort` I will convey the code I made according this enviroment

```
void removeCtrlSeq(QByteArray &data)
{
char csi = 0x1B;

if (data.contains(csi))
{
    bool inSearchForSci = true;   // flag of search activity (CSI symbol)
    unsigned int p = 0;

    for (unsigned int s = 0; s < data.length(); ++s)
    {
        if (inSearchForSci == true && static_cast<unsigned char>(data[s]) == csi)
        {
            inSearchForSci = false;   // here we found the begining of sequence - so we freez search for future steps
        }
        else
        {
            if (inSearchForSci == false && ((static_cast<unsigned char>(data[s]) >= 0x41 && static_cast<unsigned char>(data[s]) <= 0x5A) ||
                                            (static_cast<unsigned char>(data[s]) >= 0x61 && static_cast<unsigned char>(data[s]) <= 0x7A)))
            {
                inSearchForSci = true;    // here we found the end of sequence - so make search active again
                s++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (inSearchForSci == true)
        {
            data[p++] = data[s];
        }
    }
        data.resize(p);
}
}
```